# Installer CD won't boot when installing Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

I downloaded the ISO file of Ubuntu Server 12.04 (both 64 and 32 bit) and I burnt the image to a blank DVD but the installer is not booting (even when I choose DVD-ROM as the first boot device). My motherboard is ASUS, my OS is Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, Christian ! Are you installing Ubuntu Server on the same machine as the one which has Ubuntu Desktop ? If yes, you probably had to install Ubuntu Desktop by booting on a CD : try to redo exactly as you did the last time (BIOS configuration, etc).

Comment: Can you please tell us at what step you are blocked on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-server ? Could you also please edit your question to explain how you had installed Ubuntu Desktop on your computer ?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using Wubi?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ISO wasn't downloaded or burnt well. Try redoing the process, but this time on a USB key instead of a DVD.

Comment: it is burnnt well, coz i try the desktop version and its working fine. also i tried burning it 3 times.

Comment: @agmentor.. yes i did the same thing.. the installer image of ubuntu server has no autorun in its files, the ubuntu desktop have an autorun files?

Comment: there is no start.exe and autorun in the .iso i downloaded, take note i download it 5 times now. help

Comment: this is the files inside the .iso I downloaded
http://i761.photobucket.com/albums/xx252/xtiantheflow/ubuntu.jpg

Comment: Apparently you burnt the CD/USB perfectly well. Remember that is is normal that there are no .exe or autorun files, as those are Windows executables. I'll try to open a new answer when you have edited your question with the info I asked as comments to your question.